# document.getElementsByClassName giving me value undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<canvas id="can" height="500px" width="1200px"></canvas>
<div class="name">
    <h1>AISHWARYA</h1> </div>
<script>
    var name=['MOHITE','AISHWARYA',"CHANDRAKANT","KAVITA"]
    var counter=0
    var data=document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].value;
    console.log(data);
```

`undefined` is printed on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is most likely in `.value`

If you'd only print `document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0]` you'll get the inner HTML for your div - `value` is for inputs if I'm correct.

You can use `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` or `.textContent` to get the contents.

Comment: `textContent` or `innerText` not `text`

Comment: *value* is available on all form controls, not just text inputs. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expcted result, use below option of using document.getElementsByTagName("h1") and innerHTML

```html
    <canvas id="can" height="500px" width="1200px"></canvas>
    <div class="name">
        <h1>AISHWARYA</h1> </div>
    <script>
        var name=['MOHITE','AISHWARYA',"CHANDRAKANT","KAVITA"]
        var counter=0
        var data=document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML;
        console.log(data)
      </script>
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LJJdqa